# SharePoint 2013 didn't log exceptions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, logging, exception-handling

I have a problem with SharePoint 2013.
I have created a WSP package that works great on 2010 but doesn't on 2013.

Actually, when I tried to access to the page, I receive the classic "Unexpected error has occurred" with a correlation ID attached.

The problem is that at the specified correlation ID I get only:

[image: ULS log of the problem]

As you can see this contains no exception or failure neither High / Unexpected rows in the log.

I tried to check the Event Viewer: no error.
I tried to check the IIS log files: no error.
I tried to enable the classic ASP.NET view for errors: doesn't work.

How can I handle this problem without knowing which problem is? Does somebody experienced something similar?

Is there any other way to debug SharePOint operations? Actually I tried to enable as "verbose" level the information I get doesn't help me.

Why did I get the exception page if there is no exception traced?

The ASPX page I tried to access is under the _layouts folder, could this (in 2013) be a problem?

Comment: Did you convert the code in the WSP to SP 2013 code or not? The layout folder needs to be appended with 15 that is /_layouts/15/

Comment: I just changed the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll inside the project.. Is this enough?

Comment: You need to change many more things like framework, references to controltemplates, layouts etc. It actually depends on what artifacts you have in the project. You may find this likn useful:http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010.html